# How to fix "No such file or directory" occuring at exe using plotly

Tags: python, runtime-error, plotly, pyinstaller

I am trying to write a python software that uses `plotly`. The script works well when I execute it with the console. Afterward, I created an exe file using Pyinstaller. But the execution of the exe fails with the error message

> FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory
>   "Path\To\PythonScript\plotly\package_data\plotly.min.js"

Here is some information about my system:

- Operating system: Windows 10
- Python 3.7.4
- Plotly 3.10.0

---

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, plot

xValues = [1, 2, 3]
yValues1 = [5, 5, 5]
yValues2 = [7, 6, 7]

firstTrace = go.Scatter( x = xValues, y = yValues1, mode='lines+markers', name='first' )
secondTrace = go.Scatter( x = xValues, y = yValues2, mode='lines+markers', name='second' )

plottedData = [firstTrace, secondTrace]

plot( plottedData )
```

What should I do, so the exe runs without this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, PyInstaller won't handle all the module dependencies especially if they use additional files. You need to feed them manually to your final executable.

So for the [`plotly`](https://plot.ly/python/), it uses a directory called `package_data` which contains templates files, js files, etc. So you need to use [`Tree`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes) class to add it to your executable. Edit your generated spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ...
)
a.datas += Tree("<Python_Path>/Lib/site-packages/plotly/package_data/", "./plotly/package_data")
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
...
```